# getting a fieldpath errors when i am not even using it in my code

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Getting the grey screen when running in release mode the code used to run before

```
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hut/pages/home.dart';

import 'package:flutter_hut/widgets/header.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hut/widgets/progress.dart';
import 'package:timeago/timeago.dart' as timeAgo;



class CommentsState extends State<Comments> {
  TextEditingController commentsController = TextEditingController();
  String? postId;
  String? postOwnerId;
  String? mediaUrl;

  CommentsState({
    this.mediaUrl,
    this.postId,
    this.postOwnerId,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: header(context, title: "Comments"),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: showComments(),
          ),
          Divider(),
          ListTile(
              title: TextFormField(
                controller: commentsController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Write comments !!!",
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              trailing: TextButton(
                child: Text("Send"),
                onPressed: addComments,
              )),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  showComments() {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: commentRef.doc(postId).collection("comments").orderBy(
        {"timeStamp"},
        descending: true,
      ).snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return circularProgress(context);
        }
        List<Comment> comment = [];
        snapshot.data!.docs.forEach((doc) {
          comment.add(Comment.fromDocument(doc));
        });
        return ListView(children: comment);
      },
    );
  }

  addComments() {
    commentRef.doc(postId).collection("comments").add({
      "username": currentUser!.username,
      "comments": commentsController.text,
      "timeStamp": timestamp,
      "avatarUrl": currentUser!.photoUrl,
      "userId": currentUser!.id,
    });
    bool isNotPostOwner = postOwnerId != currentUser!.id;
    if (isNotPostOwner) {
      activityFeedRef.doc(postOwnerId).collection("feedItems").add({
        "type": "comment",
        "username": currentUser!.username,
        "userId": currentUser!.id,
        "postId": postId,
        "mediaUrl": mediaUrl,
        "timestamp": timestamp,
        "userProfileImg": currentUser!.photoUrl,
        "comments": commentsController.text,
      });
    }
    commentsController.clear();
  }
}
```

Error:

'package: cloud_firestore/src/ query.dart': Failed assertion:

line 310 pos 7: 'field is String || field is FieldPath || field == FieldPath.documentId': Supported [field] types are /testing/errors

[String] and [FieldPath]. See also: https://flutter.dev/docs

Comment: Was the connection to Firestore working prior to this call during the app execution? According to the comment in [this post] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64606021/packagecloud-firestore-src-firestore-dart-failed-assertion-line-49-pos-12), the error indicates that you are trying to call something before being instantiated. Can you please indicate line 310? Also, please indicate where you are initializing or getting postId, postOwnerId and mediaUrl.